# Relationship with the same table (Many to Many?) - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

In my database I have to save people and the data of people that have a relationship with the first. For example: father, mother, son, daughter, etc

Then the design of the database, I did it in the [following way](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vSet8XtNxRFY5hXNtuYvy0OUzLjyEqkO/view?usp=sharing) Is a relation many-to-many because, a person have many people related to it.

But I'm not sure if is ok..

```
class Person extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 
        'surname',
        'profile_picture'
         .....   
    ];

    public function relationships() 
    {
        return $this -> belongsToMany(Person::class);
    }
}
```

When I create the relation I create a thirth migration table call person_person to save the ids and a description (father, mother, son, daughter)

it's ok describe the relationship this way?

```
    public function relationships() 
    {
        return $this -> belongsToMany(Person::class);
    }
```

What should I add to complete successful this relationship?

Comment: I would argue against convention here.  person_person is a bad table name for family members.   Eloquent does allow you to specify your own table name.

Comment: Devon! Thanks for your suggestion.. I will change the name, but what about the relationship? is correct add the method relationship with belongsToMany()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to define the table, primary and foreign key, as Laravel likely can't determine this (it'll try, but it probably won't succeed). Something like:

```
public function relationships(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Person::class, "person_person", "id_person", "id_person_related")
  ->withPivot(["parentesco"]);
}
```

or similar. Table name is a bit awkward, consider something else, like `'relationships'` or something that conveys more meaning.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many for details on how to define additional parameters for `belongsToMany()`

Comment: I have 2 tables.. as you can see in the following [LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vSet8XtNxRFY5hXNtuYvy0OUzLjyEqkO/view)

Comment: Yes I know, and `person_person` is a pivot table between `people` and `people` (itself). This is being reflected in the `belongsToMany()`. `$this` (`Person`) belongs to many other `Person` classes via `person_person`.

Comment: Ok .. so, would the relationship be well defined?

Comment: When you add the above information to `belongsToMany()`, yes; it should be fine. Currently, it won't work; you'll get SQL errors, as Laravel tries to guess at what values to use based on the class and function names, and what you've defined doesn't match your schema.

Comment: great tim !! it was really useful .. I'm new with laravel and I didn't have idea about "withPivot" method

Comment: No problem! The `->withPivot()` method allows you to access additional columns on the pivot table, like `$relatedPerson->pivot->parentesco` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provide a nice convention for `manyToMany` relationship for two different tables but this convention does not work when we need `manyToMany` relationship in the same table.
solution steps:

1. create a pivot table and give it a meaningful name like relatives(person_person is not suitable)and create tow columns in this table persion_id and relative_persion_id.
2. with classname, pass other three arguments as the Table name (relatives), persion_id and relative_persion_id.

this link has perfect solutuion https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch/episodes/58

`public function relationships()  { return $this->belongsToMany(Person::class,'relatives','persion_id','relative_persion_id'); }`